# I selected an element by title with JavaScript, how can I update the css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I selected an element by title. From now on I want to update the css of this text. For ex. 'color: red;' how should I move on?

```
var node = document.querySelector('[title="40% Discount!"]');
```

Comment: you can use ` style `  property  ` node.style.color=red `

Answer (score 3):

```js
var node = document.querySelector('[title="40% Discount!"]').style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div title="40% Discount!">40% off</div>
```

Comment: Edited. Watch out, I think my original post mixed up jquery and js.

Comment: Thanks alot wazz, that worked perfect!

Comment: You should however not use `.style` in modern webdevelopment. The modern solution is to use `classList.add('class-name')` instead so you dont screw your specificty weight.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style properties of an existing element:

```js
const node = document.querySelector('[title="40% Discount!"]')

node.style.color = "red";
```

[More from here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In modern Webdevelopment you should not use `.style` in JS as it adds it as inline-style and as such has the highest specificity weight that only get overwritten by `!important`. The modern solution should be to add a class.

Use `classList.add('class-name')` to add a class to that element that contain `color: red;` instead!

```js
var node = document.querySelector('[title="40% Discount!"]').classList.add('red');
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div title="40% Discount!">40% off</div>
```

Comment: This one was very usefull for me. Adding class to locked html is saved my day thanks alot Tacoshy!

Comment: If that solves the issue for you, then please consider to up-vote it and mark it as an answer.